# TabStrip doesn't render data-badge when using custom icons

Tags: kendo-ui, kendo-mobile

In Kendo UI Mobile, version v2013.1.621, I use a TabStrip with custom icons. This all works well, except for when I want to add **data-badges** to it. Somehow, the webkit-mask for the custom icon/image completely 'hides' the data-badges.

My example is as follows, using Kendo's [documented approach on custom icons with webkit masks](http://docs.kendoui.com/getting-started/mobile/icons):

```js
<div id="footer-tab">

    <style scoped>
        /* Custom TabStrip Icons */
        #footer-tab .km-icon {
            background-size: 100% 100%;
            -webkit-background-clip: border-box;
            background-color: gray;
        }

        .km-demo-icon1 {
            -webkit-mask-box-image: url("images/icons/icon-1.png");
            background-color: #b2f23d;              
        }

        .km-demo-icon2 {
            /* ISSUE IS HERE: Remove the -webkit below, and the badge works. */
            -webkit-mask-box-image: url("images/icons/icon-2.png");
            background-color: #b2f23d;              
        }
    </style>

    <div data-role="tabstrip">
        <!-- Custom Icons be here... -->
        <a href="page1.html" data-icon="demo-icon1">PAGE1</a>
        <a href="page2.html" data-icon="demo-icon2" data-badge="99">PAGE2</a>
    </div>

</div>
```

Again, the custom icons work well, on both iOS as well as Android. But when I append the **data-badge="99"** attribute, the badge doesn't show up at all. By inspecting the DOM it looks like it's in place, but is just completely not visible.

Removing the `wekit-mask-box-image` line, as specified in the sample above, makes the data-badge appear, but doesn't render the custom TabStrip icon.

Seems quite straight-forward, but I can't seem to put my finger on what is wrong here. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the TabStrip button's badge is rendered inside the icon and the mask is hiding it. I've fixed this for the Q2 2013 release, which will be out this week.

Comment: Ah, that'd be great. Looking forward to it!